# How to pass the file path as an argument in RandomFileAccess Object in android?

Tags: java, android

There is a small problem in the following code that it is unable to find the text file `src/main/res/raw/dictionary.txt`:

```
 RandomAccessFile ifl = new RandomAccessFile("android.resource://" 
                               + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.dict , "r");
```

Is there any other way by which the text file can successfully be found and opened? Is there a way if we keep these files in 'assets' folder and then access? Plz suggest.

Comment: you cannot do that: res/raw/* files are not part of physical file system - you have to make a copy of that res/raw/??? file first

Comment: Can u plz elaborate where to make the copy of res/raw/??? file

Comment: get the `InputStream`  by calling `Resources#openRawResource(id)` and use it for reading

Comment: But I need to the access the file randomly which is not possible through InputStream i think..Can we keep the files in assets folder and then access them ?

Comment: use that `InputStream` to make the copy of `res/raw/*` file, and then `new RandomAccessFile(pathToTheCopiedFile)`

Comment: Well, that's a nice idea. But I don't want to make a new file and delete it every time in my app b'coz of its size.

Comment: create it once, you dont have to delete it after use

Answer (score 0):

you can better use InputStream to read text in raw folder file ,

```
 public String readRawFile()
{
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourfile);
  try {
       int count = 0;
       byte[] bytes = new byte[32768];
       while ( (count = in.read(bytes,0, 32768)) > 0) {
           builder.append(new String(bytes, 0, count));
       }

       in.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return builder.toString();
}
```